# Java issues in Downloading Large Files From HTTPS URL

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am facing issues in downloading files(more than 200mb size) from a "HTTPS URL". 
The problem is regarding the certification and downloading issues as well. I have used the **TrustManager** , **SSL security** etc codes as well. But still the problem persist mainly due to i am not able to by pass the certificate.

**Eg:** My HTTPS URL is:- `https://v1/xyz/abc.avi`. Now i want to download this file but not able to download. Small files are getting downloaded from the following code of my app:-

```
.....if (contentLength > 0) {  
       try {  
          InputStream in = urlConn.getInputStream();  
          while ( (ch = in.read()) != -1) {  
              rec.append((char)ch);  
          }  
      } ....
```

Please Help.

Comment: i am not able to download more than 150MB files from the Https url.

Comment: Why not? Does it explode? Please tell us _exactly what the problem is_.

Comment: sometimes 0 byte files get downloaded or sometimes nothing happens in case of large files.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No, I am not getting any exception.

Comment: I would definitely recommend you to use a [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) instead of reading individual bytes. But I am not sure if this is really what your problem is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading with the following code:

```
private void downloadFile() throws Exception {

        URL fileUrl = new URL("https://.....");
        URLConnection urlConnection = fileUrl.openConnection();
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/file.avi");
        BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[2048];
        while((count = bufferedInputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
            dest.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        dest.flush();
        dest.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have used the above code of BufferedInputStream and Now the files are getting downloaded but the size of the file is 0 bytes. What should i do now ??